# I can't get rid of this problem while working with gulp file TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Tags: javascript, gulp, pipe, typeerror

I am trying to setup my gulpfile for future projects and on the firt stage bumped into a problem that accompanies me no matter what do I do with my code:
Here it is :

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
    at pipe (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\pump\index.js:56:15)
    at Array.reduce (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\ometa\lib.js:101:9)
    at pump (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\pump\index.js:79:11)
    at Pumpify.setPipeline (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\pumpify\index.js:39:5)
    at new Pumpify (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\pumpify\index.js:15:30)
    at Function.Pumpify [as obj] (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\pumpify\index.js:13:44)
    at globStream (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:73:18)
    at Gulp.src (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:24:5)
    at operationsWithJsFiles (D:\HTML\NodeJs\Gulp\src\gulpfile.js:23:12)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)"
```

My code:

```
// Importing gulp modules
let {Gulp,parallel,dest,series,src, tree} = require('gulp')

let cleanCss = require('clean-css')

let uglify = require('gulp-uglify')


let scss = require('gulp-scss')(require('scss'))

let concat = require('gulp-concat')

let autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')

let path = require('path')

let rename = require('gulp-rename')

// Minimizing js files

function operationsWithJsFiles(){

    return src('js/*.js',[{allowEmpty:true}])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
        extname:'.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(concat('AllJs.js'))
    .pipe(dest('../Dist'))
}



// Minimizing scss files

function operationsWithScssFiles(){

    return src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(scss())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        cascade:false
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
        extname:'.min.css'
    }))
    .pipe(concat('AllCss.css'))
    .pipe(dest('../Dist'))
}

exports.default = parallel(operationsWithJsFiles,operationsWithScssFiles)
```

P.s: I checked my directories properly, so, I believe, gulp has no issues with finding files
P.p.s: My directory path may look confusing and hilarious xD

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```js
return src('js/*.js',[{allowEmpty:true}])
```

to

```js
return src('js/*.js',{allowEmpty:true})
```

You may have been confused by

```
src(globs, [options])
```

in the documentation, [gulp.src signature](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#signature)

But the enclosing `[]` in the signature only indicate that that parameter is *optional*.  The options don't actually go into the brackets.  So `options` is just a `{}` object.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but unfortunately your answer didn't crack the case... This array was added desparately and without it I had the same error. But appreciate your answer !

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The code runs well for me.  You will want to swap the `rename` and `concat` calls though so that `concat` happens first and then `rename`.